# How to specify which record to use when creating Nodes with an UNWIND statement in Neo4j?

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j along with the Javascript driver and I am attempting to create some nodes via a set of parameters, there are two types of records.

### The first record

---

```
testObject = {

 created: timeStamp,
 uuid: uid,
 finalScore: correctNum;
}
```

This is a central node around which I want to have lots of nodes which have the same structure (defined below).

---

### The Second record

---

```
responseObject = {

 response: finalAnswer,
 responseTime: responsetime,
 backgroundNoise: noise,
}
```

There are many of these records inside the parameters, each one has different values such as response value, response time and background nosie.

### My Question

---

```
UNWIND $responses AS responseObject CREATE (t:Test) SET t = responseObject
```

What I would like to do is choose which record gets used when creating the nodes and SETTING the properties. According to the documentation of records
a record is a form of ordered map and, as such, contained values can be **accessed by either positional index or textual key**. Can this be done at the query level when using UNWIND? For instance responseObject[2] would use the third record instead of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get just one element from a list, then use indexing, not `UNWIND`. With `UNWIND`, you'd be getting all the elements of the list.

For example, to create a node with only the third element of `$responses`:

```
CREATE (t:Test) SET t = $responses[2]
```